# AngularJS JSON response

Tags: html, angularjs, json

[image: Screenshot]

I tried accessing both `response.data` and `response.data.data`, but neither worked.

I need to get a country list for each different option from a JSON file.

```
webServices.getCountries({
}, function success(response) {
     $scope.countries = angular.fromJson(response);
});
```

My HTML:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="input4" name="countries"  >
    <option class="label">* Choose your location</option>
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `console.log($scope.countries)` output?? also create a plunker for demo.

Comment: i cant create plunker it's really complicated code.
http://i.prntscr.com/47b20958d7a643bca1b06c852406dd7d.png

Comment: Your given link is blocked on my premise. :( use imgur

Comment: try this: `$scope.countries = response.data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$scope.countries = angular.fromJson(response);
```

With

```
$scope.countries = angular.fromJson(response).response.data;
```

Comment: Didnt work no results showing. Even the output now is undefined.

Comment: Thanks the last one worked.
$scope.countries = angular.fromJson(response).response.data;

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer to remove the option that didn't work for you. Please select it if it helped you.

Comment: Where can i do that?

Comment: Next to the top left of my answer you'll see a number (currently -1) between an up and a down arrow. click the up arrow if you like the answer, the down arrow if you don't.  Under the down arrow, you'll see a check mark.  Click the check mark if you wish to select it as the answer that helped you. By the way you should probably select the answer that helped you on your previous question as well. You left a comment saying the user "saved your day" but did not select his or her answer.